# HTML Imports: Remove Import

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, html-imports

I work on a WebApp, that dynamically loads `*.html` files via XHR, takes the files `<body>` as a string adds it to the document with `insertAdjacentHTML`.
It does the same with the files JavaScript and `eval`s the scirpt tags content. (There are comments in the file denoting start end end of the relevant sections.)

I'm evaluating the possibility to switch to HTML Imports. I hope for it to be faster since it uses native functions, and does all the parsing etc.

Since I am loading *and unloading* hundrets of files over time, I need to be sure the files I import are completely removed from the DOM once I don't need them anymore. (Because of possible Memory-Leaks).

Is removing the `<link>` Tag (and the appended content) sufficient or is there more I need to do?

Comment: It should be sufficient. And there's nothing else to do. After that memory freeing will depends on the browser specific implementation